# Optimization problem of fulfill needs with selected products

Tags: .net, optimization, combinations

I've got *optimization problem* and **can't find name of it** to learn about it.

The problem is to balance all needs using combination of selected products. Ideally if there's C#/.NET lib for that

Let's say my body needs

- [Proteins = 100[g], Carbohydrates = 250 [g], Fats = 80[g]]

I decide to fulfill these needs with some combination of:

- x1[g] of Peanuts [P=26,C=16,F=49]/100g
- x2[g] of Rice [P=2.7,C=28,F=0.3]/100g
- x3[g] of Red beans [P=22,C=61,F=1]/100g

(or even some more types of food)

Costs of these products doesn't matter. Only thing I need is to meet needs (or be as close as possible if it's impossible with selected products) and if there's many combinations satisfying that condition I need to choose the option with the lowest possible weight of products: *min(x1+x2+x3)* for x1,x2,x3 >= 0

I would be very thankful if someone could fit this description to some well-known algorithm/problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like "linear equations in three variables". You can use this search term to learn how to solve it.